# Sending email from form input using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and I'm trying to send an automated email using it once the user has inputted his email address into the form and clicked submit. I have built a form where the user inputs information, including name and email. Once they click submit the inputted email address should receive an email.

I'm sorry if this is a bad question or it has been asked before but I was struggling to find my answer.

```js
// Dummy function
function getCookie(arg) { return arg }

$("form.ajax").click(function(e) {
  alert("Starting Ajx");
  var dealerID = getCookie("dealerID");
  var userID = getCookie("userID");

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://example.org",
    headers: {
      'X-Location-Id': dealerID,
      'X-Id': userID
    },
    data: {
      id: $(this).val(), // < note use of 'this' here
      access_token: $("#access_token").val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
      alert('ok');
    },
    error: function(result) {
      alert('error');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="ajax" method="POST" action="">
  <p class="error-message" id="error-message"></p>
  <select name="title" id="title" class="wrap-input2 validate-input">
    <option value="">Title</option>
    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
    <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
    <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
    <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
    <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
    <option value="Mstr">Mstr</option>
  </select>
  <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input">
    <input class="input2" name="forename" id="forename">
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input">
    <input class="input2" name="surename" id="surename" `>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input">
    <input class="input2" name="email" id="email" type="email" required>
  </div>
  <input class="spin" type="image" src="images/click.png" alt="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: AJAX can't send emails on it's own. You need a backend that can send emails or a third party service that can send emails

Answer (score 0):

agree also, Ajax is only a method to send data to the web server, it has no way to send mail directly. However you can implement a mail send function in the server which you can activate via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

> AJAX = **A**synchronous **J**avaScript **A**nd **X**ML.
>
> AJAX is not a programming language.
>
> AJAX just uses a combination of:
>
> - A browser built-in XMLHttpRequest object (to request data from a web server)
> - JavaScript and HTML DOM (to display or use the data)

There is no way to send an email using AJAX alone, nor is there a way to send an email using JavaScript alone. You can use HTML or JavaScript along with a server side scripting language, such as CGI, PHP, or ASP.NET to send an email from your web server (or a SMTP Relay).

That said, you can have the browser help the user send an email using their email program. This is done with by setting a specific Form attribute.

**Example**

```
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
  E-mail:<br />
  <input type="text" name="mail" /><br />
  Comment:<br />
  <input type="text" name="comment" size="50" /><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, the browser asks the default email program to compose an email message and direct it to `someone@example.com` and the body of the message will contain the form filed entries, like so: `[name]=[value]\r\n`.

If this is acceptable, you could do this too in your script.

```js
// Dummy function
function getCookie(arg) {
  return arg
}

$("form.ajax").submit(function(e) {
  console.log("Form Submission");
  var dealerID = getCookie("dealerID");
  var userID = getCookie("userID");
  $("<input>", {
    type: "hidden",
    name: "location-id",
    value: dealerID
  }).appendTo(this);
  $("<input>", {
    type: "hidden",
    name: "user-id",
    value: userID
  }).appendTo(this);
  $(this).attr("action", "mailto:" + $("[name='email']").val() + "?cc=myemai@address.com&subject=Form%20Submission%20From%20Website");
  return true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="ajax" method="POST" action="">
  <p class="error-message" id="error-message"></p>
  <select name="title" id="title" class="wrap-input2 validate-input">
    <option value="">Title</option>
    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
    <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
    <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
    <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
    <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
    <option value="Mstr">Mstr</option>
  </select>
  <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input">
    <input class="input2" name="forename" id="forename">
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input">
    <input class="input2" name="surename" id="surename" `>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input">
    <input class="input2" name="email" id="email" type="email" required>
  </div>
  <input class="spin" type="image" src="images/click.png" alt="Submit">
</form>
```

The user can just send the email at that point. It's not exactly the best method. It does work though.

Anything else would require a Server API that you could POST the data to and the web server would then construct a SMTP message and send it.

Hope that helps.